# Функция = Объект в JS

Tags: javascript

Почему если функция в js это объект, то мы можем её присваивать разным переменным и  созданные переменные не являются ссылками на одну и ту же функцию, а становятся независимыми функциями?

Comment: Нипочему, потому что это не так. Такие заявления надо сопровождать подтверждающими их примерами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Утверждение из вопроса:

> присваивать разным переменным и созданные переменные не являются ссылками на одну и ту же функцию

**Неверно**

Для доказательства достаточно добавить поле в функцию, например:

```js
function A() {}

var t = A;
var tt = A;
var ttt = A;

A.prop = 10;

console.log(t.prop, tt.prop, ttt.prop);
```